# Find row where values have been skipped in a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, document-automation

i have a long table like this:

```
a 1 2 3
b 2 3 6
c 4   6
d 4 4 7
e 3 3 3
f   3 6
g 2
```

in this example I would need a function now, that would return 'c' because the second value is missing. Same goes for 'f' because here the first value is missing. 'g' However is fine, the numbers just have to be filled in left to right.

I tried VLOOKUP but it has a porblem with my number being formatted as texts. Any ideas?

Comment: Does `c` represent the Excel row? Or does it represent a value in your table?

Comment: Have you tried formatting your number as a number?

Comment: and how exactly would the output look?  VLOOKUP would only return the first, but you say you should return 2.

Comment: c represents a unique id that every row has in colum A its an identifier related to some real world object. Idealy I need ALL identifiers in the matrix where the row is not correctly filled. e.g. skipped values (always looked at from left to right)

Comment: And i currently cant format the cells to represent numbers. If there is a workaround that would be great, but if its the only way I will try to adjust my Table formatting

Comment: Does your situation allow using `Autofilter`? Is there a reason your solution requires a function? And does the function require returning all results to a single cell, as `VLOOKUP` does? Or could it be applied at the row level?

Comment: Can the Autofilter combine and AND function? Because in my table there are many empty rows but they are fine, I only need the values that skip a position from left to right.  I dont need it in a single cell no, But I cant apply it to the row as my Pivot-Table with my data has about 1200 entries. And the point of this is that I dont have to check every row for it being red. But just having a list of rows that are wrong

Comment: Not quite understanding what conditions you need to help you achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

One of the many possible solutions: Fill in the extra helper column with a formula like
`=IF(COUNTBLANK(B1:D1);A1;"")`

In the result cell, place the TEXTJOIN() function, which will combine all the received object names
`=TEXTJOIN(";";1;H1:H7)`

[image: TextJoin]

Another way to quickly solve this problem is to write a small macro:

```
Function getWrongNames(oData As Range) As String
Dim oRow As Range
Dim aRes As Variant
Dim n As Long
    aRes = Array()
    n = UBound(aRes)
    
    For Each oRow In oData.Rows
        If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(oRow.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, oData.Columns.Count - 1)) > 0 Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve aRes(n)
            aRes(n) = oRow.Resize(1, 1).Text
        End If
    Next oRow
    
    getWrongNames = Join(aRes, ";")
End Function
```

Call this function from the desired cell, passing as a parameter the range with your table (like as `=getWrongNames(A1:D7)`)

Comment: The thing is, f and g are correct in your example. They have to be filled left to right just no values are allowed to be skipped

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula you can use in a helper column to determine whether row has an issue:

`=IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B1,0,0,1,COUNT(B1:D1)),"")>0,A1,"")`

[image]

If you need them merged in one list in a cell, you can use `TEXTJOIN`